# CSS3 Animation on Link Hover not working properly

Tags: html, css, css-animations

#### Background:

Trying to create an esthetically pleasing linking hover for the future

#### Current JSFiddle:

[Available here](http://jsfiddle.net/9EgUvr6tRF/) for FF Browser.

```
body {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:12pt;
    background-color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:link {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    animation: myhover 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@keyframes myhover {
    from {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    to {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

#### Problem:

The transition works in what concerns the effect, but for some reason, even if you remain with the cursor on top of the link, it reverts to the FROM state without even a fade back from TO to FROM.

#### Need:

What code change is needed to stay at TO effect, until you take the cursor out of the hovered LINK and it reverts the effect to FROM?

#### Code type restrictions:

I do not wish to use JavaScript or JQuery in the solution, only CSS and HTML.

Many Thanks
Alban

Comment: your jsfiddle is empty

Comment: This question is reading more and more like a "this is what i need doing, i've set up a workspace.. lets get on with it"

Comment: @Danny sorry didn't understand, my fiddle works... I'm not wanting you to work for me! I just want the correction...

Comment: actually the fiddle went crazy!! what kind of link is this?? http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=9EgUvr6tRF

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae A collaboration link. Great for help from a few friends, or maybe conducting a phone screen/interview. But not so great for stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae: Did either of the answers fully address your problem. I am afraid that there are no other alternates. You would either have to use JS/jQuery (or) live with the animation happening once on page load. Please do leave a comment in case you still need any help.

Comment: Hi, was on mobile and comment didn't appear. At the present time there is no more help needed. I'll have to count my losses on non-FF browsers... or use one of the proposed hacks.

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae: Not a problem mate. Can I assume that you are only trying to modify the `background-color` and `color` properties on mouse hover? In other words, does the code in question have the exact from effect you are trying to achieve? If yes, have a look at Option 3 in my answer. That will be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to `forwards` for the animation to retain the state as at its last keyframe.

```
animation: myhover 1s forwards;
```

or

```
animation-name: myhover;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[**Option 1 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/05wLa6f1/) | [**Option 2 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/05wLa6f1/1/)

**Note:**

1. The demo uses `-webkit-` prefix as I am testing on Chrome, but the same would work with either the `-moz-` prefix or without any prefixes.
2. Achieving a reverse effect on hover out would not be possible without adding extra code as `animation` do not work like `transition`. The reverse effect would be better achieved with JavaScript/jQuery as the reverse animation cannot be kicked-off by default on the base class without it appearing once on page load also. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/05wLa6f1/2/) is a way to achieve both the forward and reverse animation effects using jQuery. jQuery is not a must and the same can be done with vanilla JS also but I just used jQuery for doing a quick sample.

---

**Option 3:** (Using transtions instead of animations)

If your objective is only to linearly change the `background-color` and the `color` properties on mouse hover, then actually `transition` is a much better option to make use of instead of `animation`. Transitions can automatically answer both of your concerns. It can make the end state retained till the mouse is hovered out and the hover out will also cause the reverse effect to happen.

```
a:link {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
    /*transition: all 1s;*/ /* use this line if you wish to transition all properties */
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
}
a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

[**Option 3 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/05wLa6f1/3/)

Comment: Thanks, it works on the stopping at TO effects, but what needs to be done to revert slowly to the FROM effect (literally making the effect backwards)? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae: The reverse effect is better achieved through JS/jQuery mate. Trying to achieve that with only CSS will lead to complications and will also unnecessarily result in the reverse effect happening once on page load itself.

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/05wLa6f1/2/) is a sample for the reverse effect with jQuery. For a pure CSS alternate, refer Jack's answer.

Comment: YEP! Option 3 is what I need. My sincere thanks Harry :)

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae: Very glad to be of help mate :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your question:

**1) How do you retain the current animation state?**

Add `animation-fill-mode` to your CSS rule:

```
a:hover {
    -webkit-animation: myhover 1s;
    animation: myhover 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**2) How do you revert to the "From" transition**

Fairly straight forward - you set the "default" animation properties of the link.

```
a:link {
    -webkit-animation: nohover 1s;
    animation: nohover 1s;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The only issue you might run into is the page load. You'll notice the animations kick off before any interaction occurs (for -webkit-based-browsers). Without JavaScript, you'll need to consider this and how your animations will look.

A fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/6hxhxg5t/

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I was about to add as the CSS option for reverse effect. But yeah, the effect on page load is the killer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the animation didn't work for hover because **"Animation Starts Too Soon"**.

The original animation:

```
    .logo:hover {
       animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;
    }
```

the keyframe:

```
    @keyframes moveInRight {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px);
      }

      80% {
        transform: translateX(-10px);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0);
      }
    }
```

No matter how hard I tried, the logo just shook a little, but it never moved in from the right.

Finally I found the solution: **"Animation Starts Too Soon"**!

So I added a little delay to the animation:

```
    .logo:hover {
       animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out 0.1s; // 0.1s delay
    }
```

**And then it started to work!**

Source of solution: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-animation-not-working