# Css animation not working as it should

Tags: css, transform, css-animations

I'm a developer so CSS isn't my strong point and animations definitely not so.

However, I'm trying to create a simple animation - which now works to some degree - just not how I need it to:

```
    &:before
    {
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        height:100%;
        transform:scale(0);
        width:100%;
    }

    &:hover, &:focus, &:active
    {
        &::before
        {
            .animation(ripple .4s ease-out);

            .keyframes(ripple; 
            {
                100%
                {
                    .transform(scale(1));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The idea is that on hover,focus, or active states the background scales outward from the centre - this it does.

However when the animation is complete - and the background is fully sized, it then returns to its original state (disappears) whilst still in hover state.

What changes do I need to make to ensure the background remains visibile whilst in focus?

Comment: Try adding `animation-fill-mode:forwards` to make the animation retain the state as at its last keyframe. Moreover for this case you may be better off using `transition` instead of `animations`.

Comment: @Harry - great this works in as far as the question I asked but once the focus is removed the background simply disappears. Is it possible to reverse it out i the same way it phased in - in other words scaling from 1 back to 0?

Comment: Yea, I expected that and that's where `transition` helps instead of animation. Transition provides a two way operation by default whereas `animation` doesn't. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103506/css3-animation-on-link-hover-not-working-properly/26103639#26103639) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450535/css-animation-working-adding-class-but-not-removing-the-class/30451747#30451747).

Comment: The latter is the best option Harry - now working. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `forwards` and inbricate a `transition` with the `animation` to freeze it for a while:

```css
a,
a:before,
a:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
a:before,
a:after {
  content: "\\o/";
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 99999s;
  /* delay as much as possible return to normal */
}
a:hover:before,
a:hover:after {
  transition: 0s;/* reset transition timing */
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
  color: green;
}
@keyframes grow {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pJKOVp).

Comment: Not sure if this is something to do with my browser version (I am on old Chrome v38) but on hover out it still disappears immediately.

Comment: @Harry , you could give it a try with vendor prefix, else it is possible that animation overides transition properties. Does animation remains at 100% while hovering or does it disapear once done ?

Comment: Tried with prefix free already. Animation stays at 100% while hovering but the moment I hover out it goes blank.

Comment: sorry about this, it doesn't work either with earlier chromes. You may need a piece of javascript to overide this and toggle running/paused animation-state.